# Make the spring oauth works transparently for the user

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

I have developed a spring app (with REST services) , protected using spring oauth2 that get users credentials from Mysql database. It's work fine , i can access my protected resources using Oauth access_token . The problem is how can I do to make the processus works transparently for the user , lets me explain , for me I do the following steps to get it work :

1. I try to get the access_token from the /oauth/token like this :

   **localhost:8080/rsoneApp/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=admin&password=adminpass**
2. I request the protected resource by sending the access_token generated above :

   **localhost:8080/rsoneApp/v1/Books/getAll?access_token=b88564a5-54a2-4afa-bf4f-85aefd58412**

However like you see I should get the access_token and copy/past it as argument to get the protected resource . But for a user that should have a view that contain username & password ,

> how it's supposed to work, and where should the access_token and
>   refresh token be stored , and how to use them transparently from the
>   final user side ?

can some one give me the whole processus with an example that use a database. Am stacked here !

---

**security-config.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">

    <!--<bean name="configClass" class="com.rsone.config.PersistenceConfig" /> -->
    <!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
          authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request
         parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                       after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected
     and what roles have access to them -->
    <http pattern="/v1/**" create-session="never"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1/test" access="ROLE_APP" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>


    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password
     combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users
     credentials from DB -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>

            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                   users-by-username-query="
              select login,password,'true'
              from users u where u.login=?"
                                   authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.login,ur.authority from users u,user_roles ur where u.id=ur.user_id and u.login=?" />

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity
     and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>
    <!-- the old
    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                           resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- client -->
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                      authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                      authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                      authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                      secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the
         http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    <!-- added -->
    <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

in my database i have the user table and the user_roles table

```
user     user_roles
----     ------------
id,..    id,user_id,role
```

Answer (score 0):

have the same problem as you, I hoped that there will be a person going give everithing.
in my case when I try to access the / oauth / token using the url: localhost: 8080 / oauth / token grant_type = password & client_id restapp = & username = admin & password = password?

it does not work

that's my  xml configuration file :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled"  secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" /> 
    </global-method-security>


        <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" 
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>   
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>  
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>  
         <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                           after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    </http> 
    <!-- Protected resources -->
    <http pattern="/rest/**"
          create-session="never"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/api"
                       access="ROLE_APP"/>
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                       before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler
                ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="test"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="test/client"/>
        <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_APP"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Token Store  -->
    <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120"/>
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>   
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <beans:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
    </beans:bean>



     <!-- added -->
        <beans:bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
        </beans:bean>

    <!-- Token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                           resource-id="test"
                           token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                      authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                      authorities="ROLE_APP"
                      scope="read,write,trust"
                      access-token-validity="30"
                      refresh-token-validity="600"/>


        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"  
       authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"  
       secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" /> 


    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" /> 
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: You should specify the name of your project after /localhost:8080/ , like this 
`http://localhost:8080/project_name/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&username=admin&password=password&scope=read`

Comment: Can you post the response that you get to ?

Comment: "summary": "error=\"unauthorized\", error_description=\"No client with requested id: admin\"",

Comment: "summary": "error=\"invalid_client\", error_description=\"Bad client credentials\"",

Comment: Okye , Add the secret property <oauth:client client-id="restapp" secret="your_secret" and try this `http://localhost:8080/here_your_app_name/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=rest‌​app&client_secret=your_secret&username=admin&password=password&scope=read`